# Sum column but for each row

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to do like

[image: this]

and I want to have result like

[image: this]

and what I already try is like this

```
select no, student, sum(point) from student group by no, student
```

But the result is not like what I expected.

Comment: Your logic is not clean, show how do you get the `sum_point` of 10 and the `extra_point` of 2 ?

Comment: :( darn it I was reading the wrong column. In future would you paste in sample data as text please? (Just imagine the frustration if answers were images of queries.) Here is a link for formatting to fixed tables https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: @Used_By_Already thanks for the link and I will remember that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want a "running sum" e.g.

```
select
     no
   , student
   , sum(point) over(partition by student order by no) run_sum
from student
```

and it seems that the extra point might a subtraction of the 2nd last running sum from the final like this.

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT
        no
      , student
      , SUM(point) OVER (PARTITION BY student ORDER BY no) run_sum
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student ORDER BY no DESC) rn
    FROM student)
SELECT
    t.*
  , coalesce(t.rum_sum,0) - coalesce(ex.run_sum,0) AS extra_point
FROM cte t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 2) ex ON t.student = ex.student
                        AND t.rn = 1
                        AND ex.rn = 2
;
```

but without more guidance on the required logic for extra_point that is just a guess.

Comment: I am sorry I am not giving the explanation logic for my result but the answer above is what I am looking for. And thanks for your help I am upvote you.. :)